# Grails bindData exclude by annotation

Tags: grails

I want to exclude domain field from data binding
Is it possible to mark class field by an annotation?

For example domain:

```
class Article {
  String text
  .....
  Author author
}
```

in code I have to write bindData(article, params, [exclude: ['author']]) for cheating prevention

But much easier simple to annotate Author author. But I didn't find how.

Comment: If you want the same binding all the time, then perhaps @BindUsing will work? http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/grails/databinding/BindUsing.html and also http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/single.html#dataBinding

Comment: In this case I have to implement BindingHelper. And @BindUsing on text field not exclude author from binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Grails 2.1.0 you can use the [`bindable` constraint](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Constraints/bindable.html) to indicate that a property should not be automatically assigned during data binding.

```
class Article {
    String text
    ...
    Author author

    static constraints = {
        author bindable: false
    }
}
```

Now calling `bindData(article, params)` will automatically exclude the article's `author` property.